# Is there a way to find which user trigger the ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler in Outlook Addin C#?

Tags: c#, outlook, event-handling, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am working on an integration project, from my outlook Add-in if the user drags and drops an email I will be displaying a data entry form to store that email into my application.

Currently, if there are multiple users using my outlook addin where user a and user b have the same shared mailboxes, then if user A drags and drops an email to a shared mailbox folder, the form is displaying for both User A and User B that's not valid.

I am currently trying to find a way, is there any possibility to see which user is triggering the event or any possibility like if User A drags and drops an email to the shared mailbox, only for him the event should trigger.

Below is the simple code snippet:

```
private Interop.Items       m_hprmSentItems = null;
m_hprmSentItems = m_hprmSentItemsFolder.Items;
m_hprmSentItems.ItemAdd += MappedItems_ItemAdd;

 private void MappedItems_ItemAdd(object Item)
 {
         //my operations here
 }
```

Can someone give some pointers on this?

Comment: Do you mean more than one user accesses/modifies a shared folder in Outlook and you want to find out who caused the message creation/modification? Or do you want to record who the current Outlook user is so you won't show the generated data to a different user?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yes, correct, if a user modifies the shared folder, I wanted to know which user did that modification. Currently, I am using ItemAdd event handler for tracking email drag n drop, but that doesn't tell me which user actually does that.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if `PR_LAST_MODIFIER_xyz` MAPI properties are available in your case - they may or may not be available in the cached mode. If they are available, you can read them using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. If not, reopening the message in the online mode using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language, I am its author) is an option.

You can take a look at the available message properties in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am also its author - click IMessage button):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that Dmitry. When i am trying this, i am getting an exception "The property "PR_LAST_MODIFIER_NAME_W" cannot be parsed or has an invalid format.'"

Comment: What is your code? Are you sure such property exists on the item?

Comment: You need to pass the DASL name (displayed by OutlookSpy) to GetProperty.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any built-in property or method for getting a user name who moved the item to another folder. However, you may try using a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI. In that case you may try getting the [PR_LAST_MODIFIER_NAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/85b222f8-4d10-46bd-9fc8-8cea2fc21272) property value. Before doing that I'd suggest exploring Extended MAPI internals using an open-source tool called [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi).